# How to properly add component and repaint JPanel with component?

Tags: java, jpanel

I want to add an object to a JPanel then after a time limit repaint that JPanel and add new object.

```
package papProject;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Animation extends JPanel{

    private static boolean loop = true;
    private static int frameTimeInMillis = 10;

public static void main(String[] args){
        JPanel Ani = new JPanel(); 
        Ani.getParent();
        setup(Ani);

        while (loop) {

                Ani.repaint(); 

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(frameTimeInMillis);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }

public static void setup(JPanel Panel)
{
        Circle circle[] = new Circle[10];
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();

        jf.setTitle("Falling Shapes Animation");
        Panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jf.setSize(600,400);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.getContentPane().add(Panel);

        for(int i = 0; i < circle.length; i++ )
        {
            Panel.add(circle[i] = new Circle());
        } 
    }
}
```

This code draws the JPanels and add the circle objects to it and is supposed to repaint that component and then add a new object. I believe my problem is with the main() method.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Circle extends Animation implements ActionListener 
{

    int ranNum = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int x = (int) Math.random();
    int velY = 2; 

    Circle()
    {
        x = getRanNum();
    }

     public int getRanNum() {
       Random rand = new Random(); 
       for (int j = 0; j<10; j++)        
       ranNum = rand.nextInt(300);
       return ranNum;
       } 

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (y>370){

        velY =-velY;

    }
        y = y + velY;
    }

}
```

This code draws the Cirlce object from a random x position and moves it in the y direction. 
Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling everything from the EDT (Event Dispatching Thread).
If then you use something like

```
 while (loop) {
            Ani.repaint(); 
            try {
                Thread.sleep(frameTimeInMillis);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

That actually blocks your thread, and you're not seeing anything. Better create a new `Thread` or `Runnable` for your Animation, then start the new threads.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but in main method you repaint a JPanel but not the JFrame who is the window that show. I leave an example of your code in which I repainted the JFrame and the cirlce move!

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Animation extends JPanel{

    private static boolean loop = true;
    private static int frameTimeInMillis = 100;
    static JFrame jf;

public static void main(String[] args){
    JPanel Ani = new JPanel(); 
    Ani.getParent();
    setup(Ani);
    jf = new JFrame();

    while (loop) {

        jf.add(new Circle());
        jf.repaint();
        jf.setVisible(true);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(frameTimeInMillis);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I added `jf = new JFrame();`, else a Nullpoint Exception will be thrown.

Comment: It´s correct, because I did not put the whole code, I put "jf = new JFrame()" in the method "setup". Thanks.